# Play sound at a given volume bypassing system volume

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control

I want Ubuntu to play an alarm sound at a given volume (say, 100%), regardless of the current master volume setting.

For instance, if master volume is at 0%, I still want my alarm to play at 100%.  Is there an easy way to do this from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is: `amixer set Master 100%`.

However, that sets the master volume to 100% and then leaves it there, so the polite thing (and not easy way) to do would be:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
declare iCurrentVolume=`amixer get Master | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $4 }' | cut -c2-3`
amixer set Master 100%
ogg123 /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg 
amixer set Master "$iCurrentVolume%"
```

Where `ogg123` was what I used to test to play sounds (not standard).

*Save this file somewhere in your PATH and make it executable*

Comment: Hmmm... But this will increase the master volume while the alarm plays, so everything will be louder (e.g., any music being played).  Is there a way to just set the volume of the alarm, while keeping all the other sounds at their current levels?

Comment: I originally tried with VLC and using its internal boost... And if the volume is low (let's say 10%) you *could* boost up to double (20%), but if the volume is 0, double of nothing is still nothing! ;-) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFDcoX7s6rE

Comment: The master volume always affects all sounds played; that's why it's called "Master".